# Send HTML email with php?

Tags: php, html, html-email

I have a script that sends an email using the paypal IPN after a successful purchase. How can I modify the script to send HTML email?

```
<?php

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate

$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";

// If testing on Sandbox use: 
// $header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com:443\r\n";
$header .= "Host: ipnpb.paypal.com:443\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

// If testing on Sandbox use:
//$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://ipnpb.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

//set email variables
$From_email = "From: admin@domain.com";
$Subject_line = "Thanks";

$email_msg = "Thanks for purchasing my item. Your order will be delivered in 3-4 days. We       appreciate your business.";
$email_msg .= "\n\nThe details of your order are as follows:";
$email_msg .= "\n\n" . "Transaction ID: " .  $txn_id ;
$email_msg .= "\n" . "Payment Date: " . $payment_date;

if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
// check the payment_status is Completed
// check that txn_id has not been previously processed
// check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
// check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
// process payment

$mail_From = $From_email;
$mail_To = $payer_email;
$mail_Subject = $Subject_line;
$mail_Body = $email_msg;

mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);


}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation

$mail_From = $From_email;
$mail_To = $receiver_email;
$mail_Subject = "INVALID IPN POST";
$mail_Body = "INVALID IPN POST. The raw POST string is below.\n\n" . $req;

mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);

}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by HTML email? This code looks fine.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361762/how-to-send-html-mails-using-pear-mail for an example how to do this.

Comment: I recommend using PEAR::mail. It makes it extremely easy and simple...

http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to send full headers with content type, not just mail_from. Heres an example

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= $mail_From . "\r\n";
mail($mail_To,$mail_Subject,$mail_Body,$headers);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

In your code:

$mail_From = $From_email;
$mail_To = $payer_email;
$mail_Subject = $Subject_line;
$mail_Body = $email_msg;

mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);

The $mail_From is the fourth parameter (headers). Create a new string that contains full headers for html email plus: $_From

```
$mail_From = $From_email;
$mail_To = $payer_email;
$mail_Subject = $Subject_line;
$mail_Body = $email_msg;
//start $headers
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n"; //adds content type to headers
$headers .= $mail_From . "\r\n"; //adds the sender details
mail($mail_To,$mail_Subject,$mail_Body,$headers); //sends the email
```

If you echo $headers it will be something like this

```
MIME-Version:1.0
Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
From:email@email.com
```

Comment: Where should I put the headers? Under //set email variables? Won't they interfere with the other $header?

Comment: if you dont understand print $headers and see how it is.

Comment: I have accepted your answer but it would be good if you could post some example code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just put HTML in the mail body, and most mail clients should be able to figure it out.

A more correct answer would also include the appropriate `Content-Type` header in the mail (`text/html`).

A complete answer would be what I do:

```
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" value="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>My mail content here.</p>
        <hr />
        <p style="font-size: 8pt; font-style: italic;">Some signature here</p>
    </body>
</html>
HTML;
$text = preg_replace("(\n{2,})","\n",strip_tags(str_replace(Array("\t","<hr />"),Array("","===================="),$html)));
$seperator = uniqid();
mail("user@example.com","Title here",
        "--".$seperator."\r\n"
        ."Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n"
        .$text."\r\n"
        ."--".$seperator."\r\n"
        ."Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
        .$html."\r\n"
        ."--".$seperator."--",
    "From: My name <me@example.com>\r\n"
    ."MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
    ."Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=".$seperator);
?>
```

Not only does this send all the correct headers to leave no guesswork on the client, it also generates a plaintext version automatically for the users who don't want HTML emails.

Answer (score 0):

Sending HTML Email through PHP uses the exact same **mail** function as text email:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

$to = 'bob@example.com';

$subject = 'Website Change Reqest';

$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: susan@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1>Hello, World!</h1>';
$message .= '</body></html>';
```

Source and donwload available on [css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/)