# Sending values of a form to an email

Tags: php, html

Hello i am fensing a problem with my form sending to email. I have created a form to send values to my emal, when in press Send  button it tells me that message is sent but i can't see at my yahoo or gmail email, i am receiving nothing ...

here is my form with php code:

```
<?php 
$ToEmail = 'mr_sergios@yahoo.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Site contact form'; 
 $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
 $mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
 $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"]).""; 
  mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
?>

<?php 
if ($_POST["email"]<>'') { 
$ToEmail = 'mr_sergios@yahoo.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Site contact form'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"]).""; 
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
?> 
   Your message was sent
      <?php 
   } else { 
  ?> 
    <form action="test.php" method="post">
   <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
     <td width="29%" class="bodytext">Your name:</td>
  <td width="71%"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="32"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="bodytext">Email address:</td>
    <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="32"></td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
   <td class="bodytext">Comment:</td>
        <td><textarea name="comment" cols="45" rows="6" id="comment"  
  class="bodytext">      
   </textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="bodytext"> </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send"></td>
    </tr>
       </table>
   </form> 
 <?php 
  }; 
  ?>
```

Comment: You should check your spam section. Mails sending directly from application lands on spam offten

Comment: i checked it is empty

Comment: Aside from anything else, you should change the if statement to: if (isset($_POST["email"])) {

Comment: Your form is vulnerable to header injection attacks. Check all `$_POST` values for valid characters.

Comment: i changeg but it also is empty

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the correct SMTP settings set up in your `php.ini`. I'd recommend using something other than `mail()` anyway, as it's more likely to be reliable. Try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1361786/962144) instead.

Either that, or it's just landed in your spam folder.

Comment: [mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

Comment: here are my smtp configurations

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending it from Linux? If yes, please check `/var/log/mail.err` and see if the SMTP throws any errors.

For Windows it might be necessary to install a SMTP server, like Mercury SMTP

Comment: Try using Mercury SMTP. I'm not really familiar with Windows environment but this should do the job.
Official website: http://www.pmail.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [PHP Mailer Class?](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)

The example below is a form that submits to itself on the same page just paste the below at the very top of your contact page. Download and include your class.

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
$address = "you@youremail.com";
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
$subject = htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']);
$comment = htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment']);

$mail  = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
$body = $comment;
$mail->AddReplyTo($email,$name);
$mail->SetFrom($email,$name);
$mail->AddReplyTo($email,$name);
$mail->AddAddress($address, "Your Name");
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$mail->Send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this library: http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

It's extremely easy to setup and use, also gives you details in case of an error.