# To send sms and e-mail using php in a web-app

Tags: php

I am working on a web-app and i need to send sms and mail to those who are registering as new-user's and sending information about the update through the same

Comment: What you have done so far ? put your sample code you tried here

Comment: Then what we will do for you?

Comment: PEAR Mail for Email: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361762/how-to-send-html-mails-using-pear-mail

Answer (score 1):

You can send mail using php to use mail function following is example of mail:

```
<?php
     $to = "somebody@example.com, somebodyelse@example.com";
     $subject = "HTML email";

     $message = "
            <html>
               <head>
                   <title>HTML email</title>
               </head>
               <body>
                 <p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>

               </body>
            </html>
            ";

     // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
     $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
     $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

     // More headers
     $headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
     $headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

     mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

And for sending sms to need purchase sms gateway.

Answer (score 0):

to send sms you  will need an getway 
to send email using php use the function mail()
http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php there's you can find all the documentation

Comment: It is better to use a different mail library e.g. Pear. PHP mail() is very limited.

Comment: of course but is just a tip :)