# how to include php html file in PEAR mail

Tags: php, email, pear, newsletter

I have a php file that I use to send newsletters. Recently I moved to a new server and they use PEAR Mail instead of the default PHP mail to send mails and I had to update my script to function. But it's still not working. I get the TXT version not the HTML version.

If I manually enter the html codes inside the setHTMLBody() it works but when I replace it with my ob_start **$output_string** variable it doesn't work.

Here is my script;

```
ob_start();
include "URL/To/File.php";
$output_string = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$headers['From'] = 'from@email.com';
$headers['Subject'] = 'Newsletter Subject';

require_once('Mail.php');
require_once('Mail/mime.php');

$message = new Mail_mime();
$message->setTXTBody("Your client doesn't support HTML.");

$message->setHTMLBody(''.$output_string.'');

$mail =& Mail::factory('mail');

$result = $mail->send('myemailaddress@gmail.com', $message->headers($headers), $message->get());

if (PEAR::isError($result)) {
echo("<span>" . $result->getMessage() . "</span>");
} else {
echo("<span style='color: #f7941c; font-weight: bold'>Congratulations! 
Your mail has been sent successfully</span>");
}
```

how do I correctly input the line below correctly? It's not working as is right now.

```
$message->setHTMLBody(''.$output_string.'');
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm cold on this subject right now (working on mobile) though let's see if I can help you out. So I looked up the [setHTMLBody function](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.sethtmlbody.php). It's a little fuzzy on the *type* that the expected parameters *should* be. In PHP you can get the type using `gettype($example)` (like `console.log(typeof example);` in JavaScript though PHP is generally more forgiving about types (calculating a number that has a string type will work in PHP, not JavaScript)).

The name of the function implies that it *should* make this part of the email HTML. Now of all the modules I've built on my web platform email has been the most challenging not because it's inherently complex though because it's *very* subjective. In example some servers might expect you to serve an `<html>` element, others a `<body>` element and others won't care if you omit it (and I'm not sure what if any specifications declare what is "proper" here). I've not intentionally worked with compressing data in emails (just output in web mail though it's technical context is lost at that point). Long story straight here: the client's user agent (browser, email application, etc) should be handling the compression, not you.

PHP ob stuff is a bit convoluted. I dislike the same function/method being used for both compression and being able to capture and do find/replace with the output before sending it to a client. I *think* you're using it for compression though you could also be using it to replace bits of code for whatever reason. In this case your best bet for troubleshooting (presuming that your ob should work, most likely for replacing bits of code) is to use the string and test it outside of this environment. When I test cron jobs I always test them in normal environments *first* (though keep in mind cron jobs run in a much more limited environment so for debugging there I just have `print_r($_SERVER)` send me information via email).

So I think your ob code is messing up the parser `setHTMLBody()` function. Break your code down until you have working bits and *then* add your necessary and increasingly complex bits to it until you hit a problem and then because you know exactly what you just added you'll be able to single out the issue much easier.

I'd need further clarification though I can edit this answer later. Let me know where you're at, I always check notifications even if it takes a day.

I have a few *dozen* tools that I use when I develop. I'm not sure if this tool will validate though it may help you somehow since you are working on email. https://www.mail-tester.com/ helped me address *some* issues related to email (it's not related to this issue).

Comment: Thanks man! After troubleshooting, what I currently have is a script that works but doesn't retrieve the output_string file.

Comment: @JaySmoke Do you have error reporting for PHP enabled? If so does this script produce an error (syntax), a programmatic approach that is not syntax related or a silent error? Always go up in your code until you have what you *expect* and then you'll know *where* to look at least. Then you can focus on what you're misinterpreting on a function (e.g. incorrect use/parameters or if it's not the correct function at all). When troubleshooting you want to analyze *yourself*. In example when I realize I'm staring at the screen I know I'm done for the day. ;-) The brain is a muscle of sorts too.

Comment: Hey @John, still on this trip. I am still debugging in between other responsibilities. What I have realise is that, the ob include file is where the issue is coming from. It doesn't allow any php codes except it is in quotes. I can't use tags like <?php ?>. How can I make friendly?

Comment: Keep in mind that OB is used both for capturing output and compression and it's fairly easy to get them mixed up. I check notices so when you're back you're back. 

Comment: after thorough debugging, I found out what the problem was coming from. The ob include file was not connecting to the db so I included that info and now it's working. Took me months to figure this out because everyone kept pointing to different issues. Thank you so much for your direction.

Comment: Yeah, the thing with code is if you can't verify something go back *up* in your code. I highly recommend using `Hoo WinTail` (not free though nothing else comes close) in conjunction with a filter to load `cmdmp3win.exe` to play a sound whenever your code reports an error; obviously you'll need to ensure you have good error reporting setup. This will go a *long* ways towards helping you debug a lot quicker and well worth the effort!